# Not to able to get `props` in react js - next js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on `Server Side Rendering` react app with `React Js` and `Next Js` as my framework, and I'm trying to fetch initial props with `getServerSideProps` method by referring to the document ([next js doc for getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)) too.

But I'm always getting empty props object as `{}` on every request. For now, I'm just trying to pass a dummy text in props.

**How can I get my `props` on the initial load?**

Please refer my code below

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ConfigureStore from "../Store";

const Home = props => {
  const store = ConfigureStore();
  console.log("props", props);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>My content</div>
    </Provider>
  );
};

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const data = "Hello World";
  return { props: data };
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: You should configure your store outside your component scope !

Comment: It works with `Home.getInitialProps` but in the document, it is referred to as an old process now.

Comment: HI! Have you solved it ? Have you added _app.js file into your project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ConfigureStore from "../Store";

const Home =({ data }) => {
  console.log("data", data);
  return (
      <div>My content</div>
  );
};

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const data = "Hello World";
  return { props: {data :"Hello World"} };
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: data is giving me undefined.

Comment: I have the same problem but your answer doesn't fix it.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60656259/not-to-able-to-get-props-in-react-js-next-js-app

Answer (score 2):

The problem with [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) is that it can only be [exported from a page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page-2). You can’t export it from non-page files. Same goes with [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page).

So you can not use it in partial components.

Which means you can only use it directly on files in `/page` directory.